Forming real positive semidefinite matrices from complex matrices
I have asked this question on the Mathematics Stack Exchange: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4924554/forming-real-symmetric-positive-semidefinite-matrices-from-complex-matrices.
Let $Q \in \mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ be any matrix. When can we say that the matrix $A=Q^{t}Q$ (where $Q^{t}$ denotes the transpose of a matrix) is a real symmetric positive semidefinite matrix?
Write $Q=[q_{1}\ q_{2}\cdots q_{n}],$ where $q_{j}$'s are columns of the marix $Q$. An immediate observation is that if $Q^{t}Q$ is a real symmetric PSD matrix then $q_{j}^{t}q_{i}$ is real for all $1\leq i,j\leq n$. I am looking for some conditions to be imposed on $Q$ so that $A= Q^{t}Q$ is a real PSD.

I don't think it is possible to have a real PSD $Q^\top Q$ if $Q$ is not real.

@CarloBeenakker There are non-real complex vectors $v$ with $v^\perp v=0$, and 0 is positive semidefinite. Furthermore, there are non-real matrices $Q$ with $Q^T Q=I$ whenever $n\geq 1$. One way to see this is because the set of all complex matrices $Q$ where $Q^TQ$ forms an affine variety (or a finite union of them), and infinite affine varieties in $\mathbb{C}^n$ are never compact while the orthogonal group is compact for $n>1$, so there are other solutions.

@JosephVanName --- thank you, I was mistaken.

We say that a matrix $O$ is complex orthogonal if $O^TO=I$ where $I$ denotes the identity function. If $n>1$, then there are many complex orthogonal matrices that are not real orthogonal matrices.
Suppose that $A$ is a positive definite real matrix.
We shall show that $Q^TQ=A$ if and only if $Q=OA^{1/2}$ for some complex orthogonal $O$.
If $O$ is complex orthogonal and $Q=OA^{1/2}$, then
$Q^TQ=(OA^{1/2})^TOA^{1/2}=A^{1/2}O^TOA^{1/2}=A$. Similarly, if $Q^TQ=A$, then set $O=QA^{-1/2}$. Then $O^TO=A^{-1/2}Q^TQA^{-1/2}=A^{-1/2}AA^{-1/2}=I$.

In the case when $A$ is positive semidefinite but not positive definite, we may need to use the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse rather than the true inverse to get a similar statement in that case.
